# counting set bits of a natural number

Tags: proof-writing, infinity, binary, bit-strings

For a natural number $n$ let $f(n)$ denote the number of set bits of $n$ - which is basically the Hamming weight of the binary representation of $n$. See wiki for more info.

I have to prove that $f(n^2) = \frac{1}{2} f(n)(f(n)+1)$ for infinitely many natural numbers.
Can induction help here? It holds trivially for $1$ so maybe it is a good approach, I just do not see how to generalize it to $n$ or $n+1$.

Update: Note that for $n=2^k$ for $k>0$ we have that $f(2^k)=1$ and so when we calculate $f((2k)^2) = f(2^{2k})$ which is a power of two again so it is equal to $1$ and so is  $$\frac{1}{2} f(2^k)(f(2^k)+1) =1$$

Comment: Try with $n=2^k$.

Comment: @celtschk do I substitute this into $f$?

Comment: Could you guys look at my updated sol?

Comment: Ok deleted my comments now

Comment: @mandella yes, looks better now. Please accept one of the answers to avoid going into the unanswered section :-)

Comment: Thank you for the time

Comment: @mandella: Except for the broken MathJax it looks fine. In particular, where you wrote $(2k)^2$ you meant $(2^k)^2$ (I hope :-)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prove that for all numbers then you can use induction. But not all numbers verify this, for instance $n=3$.

You could use induction inside a set $A$ other than $\mathbb{N}$, if you suspect that all elements of this set verify your expression. In that case the inductive step will be different.

As a comment suggests, the set of all powers of 2 verify this. You can deduce directly from computations or if you really want to, induction

Comment: Could you elaborate more? I do not see the relation of powers of 2..

Comment: The relation between powers of 2 is that they are all of the form $2^k$. You can proceed by induction on $k$, i.e. prove for $k=0$ and then the inductive step for $k+1$ assuming true for $k$.

Comment: Or, you can just note that $f(2^k)=1$ for all $k$, therefore your expression holds if $n=2^k$ for all $k\geq 0$. You don't need induction.

Comment: So for $f((2^k)^2) = 1$ since $f(2^k)=1$ for $k>0$ right?

Comment: @Tal-Botvinnik: Yes, I now noticed that I misread the “$+1$” part to still be in the argument.

Comment: @mandella yes, because the square of a power of 2 is also a power of 2

Comment: Did I do it correctly on the update?

Comment: @Tal-Botvinnik: No, with my misread, you'd have $\frac12 f(2^0) f(2^0+1) = \frac12\cdot 1\cdot 1 = \frac12 \ne 1 = f((2^0)^2)$.